# File chunk upload to azure storage blob, file seems broken

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload excel file to azure storage blob in chunks, using the stage block and commitblock from BlobBlockClient Class. File upload seems to success but when i try to download and open the file, there it seems to be broken.

I'm using react and node js to do this. Code follows below

In UI

```
const chunkSize = (1024 * 1024) * 25;  // file chunk size
```

// here slicing the file and sending it to api method

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
const from = currentChunkIndexRef.current * chunkSize;
const to = from + chunkSize;
const blob = file.slice(from, to);

fileReader.onload = ((e: any) => uploadChunksToBlob(e, file, obj));
fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

// api method

```
const uploadChunksToBlob = async (event: any, file: File, obj: any) => {
try {
  const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
  const uploadChunkURL = `/upload?currentChunk=${currentChunkIndexRef.current}&totalChunks=${totalChunks}&file=${file.name}&type=${file.type}`;
  console.log(event.target.result)
  const fileUpload = await fetch(uploadChunkURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
    body: JSON.stringify(event.target.result),
  });
  const fileUploadJson = await fileUpload.json();
  const isLastChunk = (totalChunks - 1) === currentChunkIndexRef.current;
  if(!isLastChunk) {
    console.log({ Chunk: currentChunkIndexRef.current });
    currentChunkIndexRef.current = currentChunkIndexRef.current + 1;
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
    uploadFileToAzureBlob(file, obj);
  } else {
    console.log("File Uploaded")
  }
  // 
} catch (error) {
  console.log("uploadFileToAzureBlob Catch Error" + error);
}
```

}

// In Node

```
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
config.StorageAccountName,
config.StorageAccountAccessKey
);
const pipeline = newPipeline(sharedKeyCredential);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
`https://${config.StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
 pipeline
 );
const containerName = getContainerName(req.headers.key, req.headers.clientcode);
const identifier = uuid.v4();
const blobName = getBlobName(identifier, file);

const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);


try {

   let bufferObj = Buffer.from(`${file}_${Number(currentChunk)}`, "utf8"); // Create buffer object, specifying utf8 as encoding

   let base64String = bufferObj.toString("base64"); // Encode the Buffer as a base64 string

   blockIds = [...blockIds, base64String];
   const bufferedData = Buffer.from(req.body);

   let resultOfUnitArray = new Uint8Array(bufferedData.length);
   for (let j = 0; j < bufferedData.length; j++) {
     resultOfUnitArray[j] = bufferedData.toString().charCodeAt(j);
   } // Converting string to bytes
   const stageBlockResponse = await blockBlobClient.stageBlock(base64String, resultOfUnitArray, resultOfUnitArray.length, {
  onProgress: (e) => {
    console.log("bytes sent: " + e.loadedBytes);
  }
});
   if ((Number(totalChunks) - 1) === (Number(currentChunk))) {
     const commitblockResponse = await blockBlobClient.commitBlockList(blockIds, {blobHTTPHeaders: req.headers});
     res.json({ uuid: identifier, message: 'File uploaded to Azure Blob storage.' });
   } else {
     res.json({ message: `Current Chunks ${currentChunk} is Successfully Uploaded` });
   }
} catch (err) {
   console.log({ err })
   res.json({ message: err.message });
}
```

I don't know, what i'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: You don’t need to go through FileReader. Just send the chunk `blob` directly, like`fetch({ body: blob })`. Currently you convert it to dataURL that’s where thing breaks.

Comment: @hackape thank you for the comment, but still same issue

Comment: Make sure you also change the node.js side accordingly. Now that the blob is sent directly from client, thus `const bufferedData = Buffer.from(req.body)` IS THE BLOB, so you don't have to move bytes onto `resultOfUnitArray`. In other word, just use `bufferedData` in place of `resultOfUnitArray`.

Comment: And please, update your question description if you encounter further problem, provide useful info, "but still same issue" doesn't tell much.

Comment: @hackape thanks for the help, now sending the actual blob it's working.. Note: Please enter the answer so i can upvote. but now i ran into new issue i.e the specified block list is invald and for this i will raise a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you convert it into dataURL, that’s where things break.

It appears to me that you're under the wrong impression that you need to first encode a blob into string in order to send it. Well, you don't have to, browser `fetch` API is capable to handle raw binary payload.

So on the client (browser) side, you don’t need to go through `FileReader`. Just send the chunk blob directly.

```js
const blob = file.slice(from, to);
// ...

fetch(uploadChunkURL, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
  body: blob,
});
```

On the server (node.js) side, you'll receive the blob in raw binary form, so you can simply forward that blob untouched to azure storage. There's no need to decode from string and move bytes onto `resultOfUnitArray` like you currently do.

```js
const base64String = Buffer.from(`${file}_${Number(currentChunk)}`, "utf8").toString("base64");
const bufferedData = Buffer.from(req.body);
const stageBlockResponse = await blockBlobClient.stageBlock(
  base64String,
  bufferedData,
  bufferedData.length
);
```